# Javascript injection to improve SEO with Flash

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, seo

Trying to get Externalinterface in actionscript to create a hidden iframe containing xml-text content loaded and parsed inside flash. This would greatly improve SEO.
Can anyone help me with a basic as3 example to get this to work properly?

Comment: The Iframe content will not be read by search bots since it is added AFTER the page had already loaded. This is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it clear.

Search engines will not read any dynamic content.

See
[Javascript & SEO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304058/javascript-seo)

Maybe Google reads a bit of your Flash, but i wouldn't be optimistic about that.