# Does SEO-friendliness trump Elegance?

Tags: jquery, html, web-crawler, seo

I had intended to use `getJson()` to return the data I wanted to loop through with `.each()` and use in html I was dynamically building, but then I read that spiders ignore Javascript/jQuery and only take HTML into account in their indexing of web sites.

I'm assuming (wrongly, I hope) that this means dynamically generated HTML is ignored. I want the textual content of the HTML indeed to be indexed, though.

SO, I am thinking about using `$.load()` instead and passing back fully formed HTML from separate files. The data *is* static (will only be updated when I update the site) so this is feasible, but it just seems amateurish (to pass back all that literal HTML when it could be generated dynamically client-side, using the passed-back json data inserted into it) - but, if being "amateurish" is helpful to my SEO, I'll do it.

What, if anything, am I misunderstanding or failing to consider?

Comment: But content loaded via `$.load()` is still dynamically generated HTML in the sense that it is content added to the page with JS after the page loads.

Comment: Yes, but won't the spider crawl over the pages that I would be loading?

Comment: As long as you have a link to the static pages somewhere on your landing page, yes. Otherwise the spider will not be able to find them.

Comment: Would it work to add a hidden link - would that "fool" the spiders?

Comment: Even if you 'fool' the spiders, the content on your static page will be associated with that page, not your landing page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $.load() will lead you to the same problems as dynamically generating the HTML. If the spider supports one, chances are it will support both. [This discussion may provide some insight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1304128/1655495).

Can you include the static files using a server-side scripting language such as PHP or JSP? This would allow you to make edits and have them pulled in automatically while serving the HTML in a javascript-free manner.