# Do search engines index JSON results?

Tags: json, indexing, search-engine

I want to pass JSON (a small amount of which will be dynamic) from mixcloud to my podcast website

My question regards whether or not search engines will index any of the content that is sent from mixcloud when they hit my page

Certain elements of the content will be definitive to the page such as track-names, which will remain constant for ever, and since I'm, looking to stick to DRY principles, I only want to enter them on mixcloud (hence the JSON)

I've read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826275/can-search-engines-index-javascript-generated-web-pages) but my pages are not JS generated, only some of my content is

The site runs on rails so it's RESTful and yes I'm happy to just not display tracknames to people who have JS disabled so i'm only really looking to know if there's any chance of being able to index my AJAX content thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting the data from MixCloud Search Engines will index the JSON for its originating website (MixCloud) and not your website.

You can get the content indexed for your website by reading the feed/JSON from MixCloud on your server, parse it and display it as part of the HTML of your page. You could cache it on your server as well.

IMHO this is a better way to display feeds (Twitter, MixCloud, TripAdvisor, FaceBook etc) as it doesn't clutter the page with a lot of unnecessary requests to external javascript files. Let the server do the work, save bandwidth and speed up your page load time and responsiveness :)

Comment: Thankyou, I took your advice and I'm now reading the JSON through my server (with open-uri) and parsing it with the json gem. I will add caching too. I think there are still times when you might need to do it client-side but I do like the server-side method since it means my stuff gets indexed.

Comment: There are definitely times when client-side scripts are required. My background in making websites for mainly an East African audience has most likely made me a bit paranoid about unnecessary client requests as bandwidth is still a luxury in this part of the world. My nightmare being Joomla with its usual 20+ css/ js files in a regular theme ;)

Answer (score 1):

Search engines (or any visitor of your page) can index wha gets rendered; that is, whatever Firefox says is the source code for the page.