# Do search engines consider dynamic meta tags for ranking pages

Tags: javascript, html, seo, metadata, meta

Suppose I have a static page which is linked to a number of dynamic pages. I need to optimize each page for search engines. Hence, I change the keywords of meta tag dynamically for each page. What I am not sure is, do search engines take this dynamic change into account or will they just consider the keywords in the meta tag of the static page

Will Google process the JavaScript before processing the keyword metatag?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Google or other search engines execute JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364978/do-google-or-other-search-engines-execute-javascript)

Comment: Test.  Use a number or string that's unique and see if it gets indexed.  Off topic for here, though.