# Which render fastest Div, ul-li or table to show very very long list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show very very large data in a list:

1: **It should be search engine friendly**: search engine like google, bing find my content easly.

2: **It should be fast**: which is fastest amoung them.

I have tried it to small lists of local system, all takes almost same time to render.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: y not try yourself in 5 min rather than typing so much?

Comment: @ darshanags:yes all shows almost same result, currently i am using ul-li, i just thought its fast and google friendly, @Michel:main reason to ask question is about search engine

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/60-high-quality-free-web-templates-and-layouts/

Comment: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/45-free-html-css-templates-2011-2012/

Comment: http://speckyboy.com/2012/09/03/20-free-responsive-html-css-templates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would chose ul/li.  It is easily edited through css and it will take little effort to populate a list.

Anything with text will optimize your search engine, so any of your three would be fine.

Here is a topic discussing tables and SEO:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6890/are-html-tables-bad-for-seo

Comment: Thanks, :) just going to study your link

Answer (score 1):

None of them will be *search engine friendly*!

If you populate your page via JavaScript, then your HTML code is void of any content when initially sent by your server... Whether a table or a list or whatever, it doesn't exist or is empty if you deactivate JS or if you are a searchbot.
[Can search engines index JavaScript generated web pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826275/can-search-engines-index-javascript-generated-web-pages)