# SEO - Title-Tag via JavaScript after Onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Does a search engine robot sees meta information written by javascript into the the title tag of a page AFTER this page was loaded?

My Code does the following

```
<body onload="myFunction(

         //find H1 on the page and put it into the title-tag in the header-section

)">
```

Why I am doing this? Because it is one Template (same header) with different content(controlled by URL-Parameters)

So I can fill in fix meta-informations yes (same meta for all the different contents)... but I want it to be as dynamic as the content is

Someone can give me some hints or solutions?

Comment: No. And this question was already answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826275/can-search-engines-index-javascript-generated-web-pages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does a search engine robot sees meta information written by javascript into the the title tag of a page AFTER this page was loaded?

No

> Why I am doing this? Because it is one Template (same header) with different content

Improve your template so it takes the title as another field.